# extract the comment from DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

So my question is simple: from this URI --

[`http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?describe=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FRed_Dragon_%28spacecraft%29`](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?describe=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FRed_Dragon_%28spacecraft%29)

-- I want to extract specific things like --

```
rdfs:comment
rdfs:label
```

how to do that ?

Comment: Did you have a look at any arbitrary SPARQL tutorial?

Comment: @AKSW can you suggest me some

Comment: Google "sparql" for starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your query gets all properties, including `rdfs:label` and `rdfs:comment`.  To get just those properties, substitute them for `?property`, e.g.:

```
{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Red_Dragon_(spacecraft)> rdfs:label   ?label   .
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Red_Dragon_(spacecraft)> rdfs:comment ?comment .
}
```

Also, you may want to filter for language tags, e.g., `FILTER (lang(?label) = "en)`.

Comment: yes, so i want to get only the comment, how to do that ?

Comment: @scottheenginer, thanky my friend, that helped me a lot

Comment: "helpful" is often rewarded with an up vote on this forum, and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: @scottheeniger I would, really but i can't because i don't have the reputation

Comment: If you asked the question, then you should be able to accept any answer here. If not then the whole Stackoverflow system is somehow strange, I don't know.

Comment: @AKSW, sorry mate, here i did accept it, but i can't upvote it.